# How to generate additionalPropeties : {} using Swagger Java annotations or code?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have this sample Java code:

```java
class Test {
    @ApiModelProperty(value="something")
    Private String name;
    
    @ApiModelProperty(value="something")
    private Map<string,object> mapple;
    
}
```

This gives me apispec.yaml like

```yaml
name:  
  type : string  
  description : something  
mapple:  
  type : object  
  description : something  
  additionalPropeties :   
     type : object
```

I want to get `additionalPropeties : {}` or `additionalPropeties: true` instead.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask and refer the [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for guide on using markdown in Stack Overflow

Comment: What version of Springfox or Swagger Core do you use? `additionalProperties: true` is only available in OpenAPI 3.0 which requires Sprinfgox 3.x or Swagger Core 2.x.

Comment: @Helen I am using Swagger core -1.5.21 version. Can you  share me any link or provide a reference code for how can achieve this additionalProperties: true.I will upgrade the swagger version. Thanks